# How to chart live updates to logfile using matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, numpy, logging, matplotlib

Here is my code so far:

```
with open(logfile,'rb') as f:

    while True:
        lines = sum(1 for line in f)
        print lines
        X = np.arange(lines)
        data = []
        for line in f:
            a = line.split(',')
            data.append(a[1][:-2])
        print data
        Y = np.array(data)
        plt.ion()
        graph = plt.plot(X,Y)[0]
        graph.set_y_data(Y)
        plt.plot(data)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.01)
```

Right now when I print data or `Y`, it prints an empty array. Then it complains about `X` not being the same dimension as `Y` of course. I wonder if perhaps this is because data is not filled quickly enough before the print command is called? But python is supposed to execute sequentially, right?

In any case, I think the logic itself here is probably at fault. This is my best guess - open the file, and while True, try and read everything in and send it into the plot for plot.draw to use. Then as the file is growing as log files do, the chart data and the chart itself will update. How can I ensure that this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use matplotlibs animation features

You need to make an [animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) like this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/random_data.html).

### Version updating the data

Create an empty plot first and update along the way:

```
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def read(logfile):
    with open(logfile) as f:
        data = []
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if line:
                data.append(float(line.split(',')[1][:-2]))
                yield data

def animate(values):
    x = list(range(len(values)))
    line.set_data(x, values)
    ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(min(values), max(values))
    return line,

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([])


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=read('log.txt'), interval=10)
plt.show()
```

### Version creating a new plot each time

Less code, but works only for a few steps:

```
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def read(logfile):
    with open(logfile) as f:
        data = []
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if line:
                data.append(float(line.split(',')[1][:-2]))
                yield data

def animate(values):
    line, = plt.plot(values, color='blue')
    return line,

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=read('log.txt'), interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: For some reason this works for me on the first few hundered lines, then stops updating after a while - like once it gets to 250 or 300. It seems like a problem with the FuncAnimation package perhaps

Comment: You want to be updating the data in the line, not creating a new one every time.

Comment: If you use SO as a virtual code debugger - don't forget to accept answers if they work. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35567516/3904031) too.