# Matplotlib: two plots on the same axes with different left right scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use this example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html#api-two-scales 
with my own dataset as shown below:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print sys.argv
logfile = sys.argv[1]
data = []
other_data =[]
with open(logfile,'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split(',')
        print a
        data.append(a[1])
        other_data.append(a[2][:-1])
print other_data
x = np.arange(0,len(data))
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x,np.arange(data))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x,np.arange(other_data))
plt.show()
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "share/chart.py", line 17, in <module>
    ax1.plot(x,np.arange(data))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

I think I am using the twinx command correctly but apparently not. How can I do this?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be originating from `twinx` it seems to be located in either `x` or `np.arange(data)` when they're being passed to the plotting function. I would check that to make sure they output what you expect them to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
x1.plot(x,np.array(data))  # do you mean "array" here?
```

in both places, instead of

```
x1.plot(x,np.arange(data))
```

But why do you want to use anything here at all? If you just

```
x1.plot(data)
```

it will generate your x values automatically, and `matplotlib` will handle a variety of different iterables without converting them.

You should supply an example that someone else can run right away by adding some sample data. That may help you debug also. It's called a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

You can get rid of some of that script too:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

things = ['2,3', '4,7', '4,1', '5,5']

da, oda = [], []
for thing in things:
    a, b = thing.split(',')
    da.append(a)
    oda.append(b)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2      = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(da)
ax2.plot(oda)

plt.savefig("da oda")  # save to a .png so you can paste somewhere
plt.show()
```

**note 1:** `matplotlib` is generating the values for the x axis for you as default. You can put them in if you want, but that's just an opportunity to make a mistake.

**note 2:** `matplotlib` is accepting the strings and will try to convert to numerical values for you.

if you want to embrace python, use a list comprehension and then `zip(*)` - which is the inverse of `zip()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

things = ['2,3', '4,7', '4,1', '5,5']

da, oda = zip(*[thing.split(',') for thing in things])

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2      = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(da)
ax2.plot(oda)

plt.savefig("da oda")  # save to a .png so you can paste somewhere
plt.show()
```

But if you *really really want* to use arrays, then transpose - `array.T` - <s>does what `zip(*)` does</s> will also work for nested iterables. However you should convert to numerical values first using `int()` or `float()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

things = ['2,3', '4,7', '4,1', '5,5']

strtup = [thing.split(',') for thing in things]
inttup = [(int(a), int(b)) for a, b  in strtup]

da, oda = np.array(inttup).T

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2      = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(da)
ax2.plot(oda)

plt.savefig("da oda")
plt.show()
```

[image]